# Programmatically select an item from a drop down in .NET Webbrowser Control

Tags: c#, javascript, html, .net

Below is a html script, I grabbed from a website. I wanna select the item programmatically using .NET

```
<div id="MySite.condition_s-wrp" class="c-wrp-slctbx" style="z-index: 1;">
    <input id="MySite.condition_s-input" type="text" autocomplete="off" readonly="readonly" tabindex="0" class=" c-slctbx-medium" style="width: 268px;">
    <ul class="c-ul-slctbx max_height_300" style="width: 285px; display: none; top: 21px;">
        <li id="MySite.condition_s-option-" class="c-li-slctbx">Please choose</li>
        <li id="MySite.condition_s-option-First" class="c-li-slctbx">First</li>
        <li id="MySite.condition_s-option-Second" class="c-li-slctbx">Second</li>
    </ul>
    <select id="MySite.condition_s" name="attributeMap[MySite.condition_s]" class=" c-slctbx-medium" style="display: none;">
        <option value="">Please choose</option>
        <option value="First">First</option>
        <option value="Second">Second</option>
        </select>
</div>
```

Please note the following code is not working at all.

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("MySite.condition_s").SetAttribute("value", "First");
```

Any quick help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You could fetch the `select`s children and set the attribute `selected` on one of them.

Comment: Explain "is not working at all".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally I figure it out with one of my friends. This little function will do the rest very easily.

Thanks to Farrukh Momin and his time.

```
    public void SetComboItem(string id, string value) {
        HtmlElement ee = this.webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById(id);
        foreach (HtmlElement item in ee.Children) {
            if (item.OuterHtml.ToLower().IndexOf(value.ToLower()) >= 0) {
                item.SetAttribute("selected", "selected");
                item.InvokeMember("onChange");
            }
            else {
                item.SetAttribute("selected", "");
            }
        }

        ee = this.webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById(id + "-input");
        ee.InnerText = value;
    }
```

Calling Function

```
    this.SetComboItem("MySite.condition_s", "First");
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this:

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("MySite.condition_s").selectedIndex = 1
```

Comment: I am afraid, but there is no selectedIndex property.

Comment: You probably will have to cast to the dropdown control first. `GetElementById` returns an `Element`, which doesn't have that property.

Comment: None of the solutions are working, I think something to do with the INPUT and UL and not with the SELECT & OPTION. I am really vary bad in html & javascript :(.

Comment: Does `webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("MySite.condition_s")` return anything at all ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
   HtmlDocument document = webBrowser1.Document;
        HtmlElement siteCondition = document.GetElementById("MySite.condition_s");

        var option = siteCondition.Children.Cast<HtmlElement>().First(x => x.GetAttribute("value").Equals("First"));
        option.SetAttribute("selected", "selected");
```

Comment: None of the solutions are working, I think something to do with the INPUT and UL and not with the SELECT & OPTION. I am really vary bad in html & javascript :(.

Answer (score 1):

here is your solution just go through example: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?701093-Webbrowser-Control-Select-Dropdownlists-option

or

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/Vsexpressvb/thread/b1273d78-d4af-49e0-9238-6f86e9952484/

Comment: None of the solutions are working, I think something to do with the INPUT and UL and not with the SELECT & OPTION. I am really vary bad in html & javascript :(.

Comment: look at your code once again with cool mind.u wil get it.all d best.

Answer (score 0):

I founded that if you just invoke click one by one, you should be able to find what you want by doing a for loop click inside it.

```
HtmlElement site = this.webBrowser2.Document.GetElementById("myId");
foreach (HtmlElement item in site.Children)
{ 
   if (item.InnerText.ToString() == "something")
   {
       item.InvokeMember("Click");
             break;
   }
       else
   {
       item.InvokeMember("Click");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**100% working code (tested on win7 - ie11)**

taken from:

c# | WebBrowser control - programmatically select item on html select
http://mdb-blog.blogspot.com/2016/12/c-browser-control-programmatically.html

```
HtmlElementCollection col = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("select") 
foreach (HtmlElement heItem in col) 
{ 
  if (heItem.GetAttribute("className").Contains("exampleClassName") == true) 
  { 
    heItem.SetAttribute("selectedIndex", "3"); // select value at #3
    break; // incase of needed... 
  } 
}
```