# how to fill the SELECT of a web form with .net and webbrowser

Tags: c#, vb.net, webforms, webbrowser-control

I'm attempting to fill in the `<SELECT>` of a web page using webbrowser. I'm having some luck. One I can complete and the other is alluding me. The section I CAN update looks like this:

```
 <select class="width-80" id="yesNo" name="yesNo" tabindex="1" data-placeholder="Select Yes/No..." data-bind="value: yesNo">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="1">Yes</option>
  <option value="2">No</option>
</select>
```

The SELECT I can't fill out looks like this:

```
<select class="width-80 chosen-select" name="listOfStuff" id="listOfStuff" tabindex="2" data-bind="value: ListDetails().ListID, selectedText: ListDetails().ListDesc" data-placeholder="Select a thing..."></select>
```

The Inspector view shows a bit more...

```
<SELECT>....as above</SELECT>
<div id="stuff_chosen">
<a class="chosen-thing">
<span>Thingo 1</span>
</a>
<div class="selected-dropdown">
<ul class="search results">
<li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-index="0">Please select country</li>
<li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-index="1">United States</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

so with th econstruction of the second one, I'm unable to use:

```
.SetAttribute("selected", "selected")
```

...further edits for clarity...

Below is the code that works on the yesNo select but not the stuff_chosen select.

```
For Each oElement as HTMLElement In WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("yesNo").Children
  If oElement.InnerHtml = "Yes" Then oElement.SetAttribute("selected", "selected")
Next
```

Comment: What's the .net issue here? this is HTML. Where is c# or vb?

Comment: HI there. The .SetAttribute example - the last line in the post - is the vb.net you ask for.

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/a/15283749/1704458

Comment: I tried that one. No children are being found, so the code doesn't itterate through anyting.

Comment: you probably need to invoke the click event handler of the country item, which is obviously hooked up to a script function from elsewhere.

Comment: Jiang, sounds reasonable. Here is what I've tried so far:
   l_oHTMLElement = m_oWebbrowser.Document.GetElementById("listOfStuff")
                        l_oHTMLElement.Focus()
                        l_oHTMLElement.InvokeMember("click")
                        l_oHTMLElement.InvokeMember("trigger")
                        l_oHTMLElement.InvokeMember("change")
                        l_oHTMLElement.SetAttribute("selected", "selected")
oHTMLElement.InvokeMember("blur")
                        oHTMLElement.RemoveFocus()

Comment: So it turns out my code for manipulating the web page was running faster that the web page would construct itself.
A database lookup was used to populate a datalist, which in turn was used to populate the select options. My code was executing before the population could begin.
I resolved the issued with a rather fudgy:

    `Do
      l_oElementCollection = m_oWebrowser1.Document.GetElementById("listOfStuff").Children
      Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents()
    Loop Until l_oElementCollection.Count > 250`

Is there a better way?

Comment: Is the page using Ajax to populate the items?

Comment: I don't know. How would I find out?

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out my code for manipulating the web page was running faster that the web page would construct itself.
A database lookup was used to populate a datalist, which in turn was used to populate the select options. My code was executing before the population could begin.
I resolved the issued with a rather fudgy:

```
Do
  l_oElementCollection = m_oWebrowser1.Document.GetElementById("listOfStuff").Children
  Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents()
Loop Until l_oElementCollection.Count > 250
```